# Input box not being responsive

Tags: html, css

[css]

```
.inputBox {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 16px;
  padding: 4px 6px 0 6px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #555555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

[html]

```
<input class="inputBox" type="text" name="myinput" />
```

**It is not showing up in the middle on mobile**

What else do I need to add to either the CSS or HTML? Please advise.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is it that you want it to do...?

Comment: It is not showing up in the middle on mobile.

Comment: In the middle of what? You need to post more context, we have no idea what your page is like. Plus you have two `vertical-align`s. The other one won't do anything.

Comment: give a `width` and `margin:0 auto`

Comment: Well, first off, in order to use an inset box-shadow in an input, you need to set the input's background. Like this: `background: #fff;`. It's hard to help with so little description :(

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen in the middle of the page..

Answer (score 0):

set input's parent div style like below.

```
.parent{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

and give style to your input tag like below:

```
.parent input{
   float:none;
   margin:0 auto;
   position:relative:
   margin-top:50%;
}
```

checkout fiddlle : http://jsfiddle.net/cvbvo104/